# Combining two Gaussian posterior distributions from different data to refine estimated distribution.

Tags: statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian, bayes-theorem

If we apply Bayesian inference to try and determine the distribution of a multivariate Gaussian $\textbf{x}$, and we have two predictions

$$
\textbf{x}\sim N(\textbf{a}_1,\Sigma _1)~~ and ~~ \textbf{x}\sim N(\textbf{a}_2,\Sigma _2)
$$
based on different data sets then is there a way of combining these into a single refined estimate of the distribution of $\textbf{x}$? I want to just multiply the two Gaussians since this gives a Gaussian, but the result in un-normalised and so isn't a PDF. Can we simply normalise the product?

Answer (score 0):

Take a covariance weighted average.

(Also, your notation here needs fixing: you need to define the x as samples from a distribution)